# Rails console errors on missing nokogiri gemspec, but nokogiri has no gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, bundler

I tried to reinstall Ruby 2.3.6 through RVM to fix some errors, where I had to explicitly specify the OpenSSL path to get it to reinstall. After installing bundler and running `bundle install` in my project directory, I tried to run `rails c` and `bundle exec rails c`, only to get this error:

```
/Users/abhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.6@px-core/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/stub_specification.rb:97:in `_remote_specification': The gemspec for nokogiri-1.10.1 at /Users/abhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.6@px-core/specifications/nokogiri-1.10.1.gemspec was missing or broken. Try running `gem pristine nokogiri -v 1.10.1` to fix the cached spec. (Bundler::GemspecError)
```

However, Nokogiri has no gemspec, and running the suggested `gem pristine` command didn't change anything. I checked that Nokogiri is listed in my Gemfile. None of my team members are facing the same issues. How can I diagnose & fix this problem?

Update: `bundle exec gem pristine nokogiri -v 1.10.1` errored with:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/abhaskar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.6/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri
/Users/abhaskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190130-46592-q2jdnm.rb extconf.rb
/Users/abhaskar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.10.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Comment: Are you using the expected version of ruby installed through RVM? That might be it and why `gem pristine` didn't work...

Comment: How can I check that? Would I need to run `bundle exec gem pristine`?

Comment: That might be worth a shot. (You do seem to have a rather strange case here.)

Comment: Also try `gem uninstall` if that doesn't work

Comment: I think running `bundle exec gem pristine` uninstalled the package somehow - `gem uninstall nokogiri` output that nokogiri wasn't installed after running the `pristine` command.

Comment: try `gem install` (with the version flag if needed) then :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up right back where I started with the same error.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my strong advice: bail on rvm and move to docker.  You get a clean build every time.  No worrying about mixing system libs between different projects.  etc.

There is a little overhead in getting to know docker, but once you do you're free to run any version of postgres/mysql/rails/ruby/whatever and mix and match however you like.